# Paint View Zoom with Image problem

Tags: android, view, zooming, paint

anyone knows how to zoom paint view with image correctly?

At following code, I used canvas zoom in order to zoom paint view with image including using setImageMatrix().
But problem arised, that is entire screen became to zoom in/out but not paint view and image only.
So If anyone knows this issue, reply plz.

PaintScreen.java

```
public class PaintScreen extends Activity implements ColorPickerDialog.OnColorChangedListener{

    Context mContext;
    private Paint mPaint;
    MaskFilter  mEmboss;
    MaskFilter  mBlur;    
    private ImageView mImageView; 
    private LinearLayout mPaintBaseLayout;
    private FrameLayout mTouchBaseLayout;
    private PaintView mPaintView;
    private int[] mPixels;
    private Bitmap mBitmapImage;

    private DisplayMetrics mDisplayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    MultiTouchListener multiTouchLitener = new MultiTouchListener(this);

      private static final String TAG = "Touch";
       // These matrices will be used to move and zoom image
       Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
       Matrix savedMatrix = new Matrix();
      Matrix savedMatrix2 = new Matrix();

      private  int WIDTH = 0;
      private  int HEIGHT = 1;

       // We can be in one of these 3 states
       static final int NONE = 0;
       static final int DRAG = 1;
       static final int POINT2 = 2;
       static final int ZOOM = 3;
       int mode = NONE;

       // Remember some things for zooming
       PointF start = new PointF();
       PointF mid = new PointF();
       float oldDist = 1f;
      float newDist;
      float distanceOffset = 50f;
      float minOffset = 50f;
      float maxOffset = 10000f;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {    
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.paint_mode1_paint);

        this.initialize();

        this.PaintSet();
    }

    private void initialize()
    {
        mPaintBaseLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.paint_paint_base_layout);
        mTouchBaseLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.paint_touch_base_layout);

        mContext = this;
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaintView = new PaintView(mContext);
        mPaintView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        mPaintBaseLayout.addView(mPaintView, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        mPaintBaseLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

        mPaintView.setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);
        mPaintView.setMPaint(mPaint);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle itstr = intent.getExtras();
        String imagePath = itstr.getString("image_path");

        Drawable d = Drawable.createFromPath(imagePath);

        mPaintView.setBackgroundDrawable(d);

        mPaintView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                dumpEvent(event);
                PaintView view = (PaintView) v;

                switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                    start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                    oldDist = spacing(event);
                    if (oldDist > 10f) {
                        start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
                        savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                        midPoint(mid, event);
                        mode = POINT2;
                    }
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                     mode = NONE;
                     distanceOffset = minOffset;
                     break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    if (mode == POINT2)
                     {
                        newDist = spacing(event); 
                        if (newDist - oldDist > 5f 
                                || newDist - oldDist < -5f) {
                            mode = ZOOM;
                        } else {
                            start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
                            mode = DRAG;

                        } 
                     } else           
                     if (mode == DRAG) {
                            matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                            matrix.postTranslate(event.getX() - start.x,
                                  event.getY() - start.y);


                     }
                     else if (mode == ZOOM) {
                        newDist = spacing(event);
                        if (newDist > 10f) {

                             matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                             float scale = newDist / oldDist;
                             matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);


                        }
                     } else {

                         view.onTouchEvent(event);
                     }
                    break;

                }

                matrixTurning(matrix, view);                
                view.setImageMatrix(matrix);
                view.cMatrix(matrix);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

       /** Show an event in the LogCat view, for debugging */
       private static void dumpEvent(MotionEvent event) {
          String names[] = { "DOWN", "UP", "MOVE", "CANCEL", "OUTSIDE",
                "POINTER_DOWN", "POINTER_UP", "7?", "8?", "9?" };
          StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
          int action = event.getAction();
          int actionCode = action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;
          sb.append("event ACTION_").append(names[actionCode]);
          if (actionCode == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN
                || actionCode == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP) {
             sb.append("(pid ").append(
                   action >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_ID_SHIFT);
             sb.append(")");
          }
          sb.append("[");
          for (int i = 0; i < event.getPointerCount(); i++) {
             sb.append("#").append(i);
             sb.append("(pid ").append(event.getPointerId(i));
             sb.append(")=").append((int) event.getX(i));
             sb.append(",").append((int) event.getY(i));
             if (i + 1 < event.getPointerCount())
                sb.append(";");
          }
          sb.append("]");
          Log.d(TAG, sb.toString());
       }

       /** Determine the space between the first two fingers */
       private static float spacing(MotionEvent event) {
          float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
          float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
          return FloatMath.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
       }

       /** Calculate the mid point of the first two fingers */
       private static void midPoint(PointF point, MotionEvent event) {
          float x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);
          float y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);
          point.set(x / 2, y / 2);
       }

   private  void matrixTurning(Matrix matrix, ImageView view){

           float[] value = new float[9];
           matrix.getValues(value);
           float[] savedValue = new float[9];
           savedMatrix2.getValues(savedValue);

           // view size
           int width = view.getWidth();
           int height = view.getHeight();

           //image size
           Drawable d = view.getDrawable();
           if(d == null) return;
           int imageWidth = d.getIntrinsicWidth();
           int imageHeight = d.getIntrinsicHeight();
           int scaleWidth = (int)(imageWidth*value[0]);
           int scaleHeight = (int)(imageHeight*value[0]);


           if(value[2] < width - scaleWidth) value[2] = width - scaleWidth;
           if(value[5] < height - scaleHeight) value[5] = height - scaleHeight;
           if(value[2] > 0) value[2] = 0;
           if(value[5] > 0) value[5] = 0;

           if(value[0] > 10 || value[4] > 10){
               value[0] = savedValue[0];
               value[4] = savedValue[4];
               value[2] = savedValue[2];
               value[5] = savedValue[5];
           }

           if(imageWidth > width || imageHeight > height){

               if(scaleWidth < width && scaleHeight < height){
                   int target = WIDTH;

                   if(imageWidth < imageHeight) target = HEIGHT;

                   if(target == WIDTH) value[0] = value[4] = (float)width/imageWidth;
                   if(target == HEIGHT) value[0] = value[4] = (float)height/imageHeight;


                   scaleWidth = (int)(imageWidth*value[0]);
                   scaleHeight = (int)(imageHeight*value[4]);

                   if(scaleWidth == width) value[0] = value[4] = (float)width/imageWidth;
                   if(scaleHeight == height) value[0] = value[4] = (float)height/imageHeight;
               }


           }else{
               if(value[0] < 1) value[0] = 1;
               if(value[4] < 1) value[4] = 1;
           }



           scaleWidth = (int)(imageWidth*value[0]);
           scaleHeight = (int)(imageHeight*value[4]);

           if(scaleWidth < width){
               value[2] = (float)width/2-(float)scaleWidth/2;
           }
           if(scaleHeight < height){
               value[5] = (float)height/2-(float)scaleHeight/2;
           }


           matrix.setValues(value);
           savedMatrix2.set(matrix);


       }               

    public void PaintSet(){

        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setDither(true);
        mPaint.setColor(0xFFFF0000);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(24);

        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(mDisplayMetrics);
        mEmboss = new EmbossMaskFilter(new float[] { 1, 1, 1 }, 0.4f, 6, 3.5f);
        mBlur = new BlurMaskFilter(24, BlurMaskFilter.Blur.NORMAL);     
    }

    public void colorChanged(int color) {
        mPaint.setColor(color);
    }
}


PaintView.java

public class PaintView extends ImageView {

    private Context mContext;

    private static final float MINP = 0.25f;
    private static final float MAXP = 0.75f;

    private Bitmap  mBitmap;
    private Bitmap  testBitmap;
    private Canvas  mCanvas;
    private Canvas  tCanvas;
    private Path    mPath;
    private Paint   mBitmapPaint;

    // onDraw
    private Paint       mPaint;
    private MaskFilter  mEmboss;
    private MaskFilter  mBlur;

    // onTouch
    private float mX, mY;
    private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;


    public PaintView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public PaintView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        mContext = context;

        mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(320, 480, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        //mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
        mPath = new Path();
        mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        //canvas.drawColor(0xFFAAAAAA);
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        mCanvas = canvas;
        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);

        canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);

    }

    public void setMPaint(Paint paint) {
        mPaint = paint;
    }

    private void touchStart(float x, float y) {
        mPath.reset();
        mPath.moveTo(x, y);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
    }

    private void touchMove(float x, float y) {
        float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
        float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
        if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
            mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX)/2, (y + mY)/2);
            mX = x;
            mY = y;
        }
    }

    private void touchUp() {
        mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
        // commit the path to our offscreen
        mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
        // kill this so we don't double draw
        mPath.reset();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();

        Log.d("PaintView", "ev ->" + event.getAction());

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                touchStart(x, y);
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                touchMove(x, y);
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                touchUp();
                invalidate();
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void cMatrix(Matrix matrix) {
    mCanvas.setMatrix(matrix);
    }

}
```

Comment: i am same problem.but no any solution.have solved this one ?

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    //canvas.drawColor(0xFFAAAAAA);
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    mCanvas = canvas;
    canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);

    canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);

}
```

In this method you write, mCanvas = canvas; instead of this write,  canvas = mCanvas.

Answer (score 0):

Hello try with below code for paint and capture new bitmap with pain image.first zoom in/out image and on button click draw paint.then click on done button for save your final merge bitmap.Hop its helpful to you.

```
 public class PaintScreen extends Activity {

    Context mContext;
    private Paint mPaint;
    MaskFilter mEmboss;
    MaskFilter mBlur;
    private LinearLayout mPaintBaseLayout, mPaintBaseLayout2;
    private PaintView mPaintView;

    // These matrices will be used to move and zoom image
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    Matrix matrix1 = new Matrix();
    Matrix savedMatrix = new Matrix();
    Matrix savedMatrix2 = new Matrix();
    Matrix dmMtrx = new Matrix();

    private int WIDTH = 0;
    private int HEIGHT = 1;

    // We can be in one of these 3 states
    static final int NONE = 0;
    static final int DRAG = 1;
    static final int POINT2 = 2;
    static final int ZOOM = 3;
    int mode = NONE;
    private static final float MIN_ZOOM = 0.0f;
    private static final float MAX_ZOOM = 1.0f;


    // Remember some things for zooming
    PointF start = new PointF();
    PointF mid = new PointF();
    float oldDist = 1f;
    float newDist;
    float distanceOffset = 50f;
    float minOffset = 50f;
    float maxOffset = 10000f;
    private boolean falg = true;
    private int startval = 0;
    Bitmap newbm;
    private float finalscale;
    Bitmap bm;
    private float scaledImageOffsetX;
    private float scaledImageOffsetY;
    ImageView imageView;
    ProgressDialog dialog;
    private float[] matrixValues;
    Bitmap temp;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_image_main);

        this.initialize();

        this.PaintSet();
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview1);
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnzoom);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (falg) {
                    getFlag(false);
                } else {
                    getFlag(true);
                }
            }
        });

        Button btnset = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnset);
        btnset.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startval = 1;
                mPaintBaseLayout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                /*newbm = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm.getWidth(),
                        bm.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                Canvas canvas = new Canvas(newbm);
                mPaintBaseLayout.draw(canvas);*/
                // mPaintView.clear();
/*
                mPaintView.setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);
                mPaintView.setMPaint(mPaint);
                mPaintView.setImageBitmap(newbm);*/

                imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                mPaintBaseLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                new SaveImageAsynk().execute();
            }
        });

        imageView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                ImageView view = (ImageView) v;

                switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    savedMatrix.set(matrix1);
                    start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
                    mode = DRAG;
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                    oldDist = spacing(event);
                    if (oldDist > 10f) {
                        start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
                        savedMatrix.set(matrix1);
                        midPoint(mid, event);
                        // mode = POINT2;
                        mode = ZOOM;
                    }
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    mode = NONE;
                    distanceOffset = minOffset;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                    mode = NONE;
                    distanceOffset = minOffset;
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    if (mode == POINT2) {
                        newDist = spacing(event);
                        if (newDist - oldDist > 5f
                                || newDist - oldDist < -5f) {
                            mode = ZOOM;
                        } else {
                            start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
                            mode = DRAG;
                        }
                    } else if (mode == DRAG) {
                        matrix1.set(savedMatrix);
                        matrix1.postTranslate(event.getX() - start.x,
                                event.getY() - start.y);
                    } else if (mode == ZOOM) {
                        newDist = spacing(event);
                        if (newDist > 10f) {
                            matrix1.set(savedMatrix);
                            float scale = newDist / oldDist;
                            matrix1.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x,
                                    mid.y);
                            finalscale = scale;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                }

                view.setImageMatrix(matrix1);
//              matrixTurning(matrix1, view);
                return true; // indicate event was handled
            }
        });
    }

    class SaveImageAsynk extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{
        Bitmap tempBm;
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            temp = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, bm.getWidth(), bm.getHeight(), matrix, false);
            newbm = Bitmap.createBitmap(mPaintBaseLayout.getWidth(),
                    mPaintBaseLayout.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(newbm);
            mPaintBaseLayout.draw(canvas);
            tempBm = combineImages(newbm, temp);
            if (newbm != null) {
                newbm = null;
            }
            if (temp != null) {
                temp = null;
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(tempBm);
            try {
                dialog.dismiss();
                if (dialog != null) {
                    dialog = null;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(PaintScreen.this);
            dialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            dialog.show();
        }

    }
    public Bitmap combineImages(Bitmap c, Bitmap s) {
        Bitmap cs = null;

        int width, height = 0;

        if (c.getWidth() > s.getWidth()) {
            width = c.getWidth();
            height = c.getHeight() + s.getHeight();
        } else {
            width = s.getWidth();
            height = c.getHeight() + s.getHeight();
        }
        Log.e("hw :", "X = "+width + " Y = "+height);
        cs = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        Canvas comboImage = new Canvas(cs);
        comboImage.drawBitmap(s,new Matrix(), null);
        comboImage.drawBitmap(c,Math.abs(scaledImageOffsetX),Math.abs(scaledImageOffsetY), null);

        return cs;
    }

    private void initialize() {
        mPaintBaseLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.paint_paint_base_layout);
        mPaintBaseLayout2 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.paint_paint_base_layout2);

        mContext = this;
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaintView = new PaintView(mContext);
        mPaintView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        mPaintBaseLayout.addView(mPaintView, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        mPaintBaseLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

//      mPaintView.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        mPaintView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
        mPaintView.setMPaint(mPaint);
        bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.nat);

        mPaintView.setImageBitmap(bm);

        mPaintView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                PaintView view = (PaintView) v;
                view.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);
                switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    if (falg) {
                        savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                        start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
                        mode = DRAG;
                    } else {
                        view.onTouchEvent(event);
                    }
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                    if (falg) {
                        oldDist = spacing(event);
                        if (oldDist > 10f) {
                            start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
                            savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                            midPoint(mid, event);
                            mode = ZOOM;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    if (falg) {
                        mode = NONE;
                        distanceOffset = minOffset;
                    }
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                    if (falg) {
                        mode = NONE;
                        distanceOffset = minOffset;
                    }
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    if (falg) {
                        if (mode == POINT2) {
                            newDist = spacing(event);
                            if (newDist - oldDist > 5f
                                    || newDist - oldDist < -5f) {
                                mode = ZOOM;
                            } else {
                                start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
                                mode = DRAG;
                            }
                        } else if (mode == DRAG) {
                            matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                            matrix.postTranslate(event.getX() - start.x,
                                    event.getY() - start.y);
                        } else if (mode == ZOOM) {
                            newDist = spacing(event);
                            if (newDist > 10f) {
                                matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                                float scale = newDist / oldDist;
                                matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);
                                finalscale = scale;
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        view.onTouchEvent(event);
                    }
                    break;
                }

                limitZoom(matrix);
                view.setImageMatrix(matrix);

                matrixTurning(matrix, view);
                RectF r = new RectF();
                matrix.mapRect(r);
                scaledImageOffsetX = r.left;
                scaledImageOffsetY = r.top;

                return true;
            }
        });
    }


    private void limitZoom(Matrix m) {

        float[] values = new float[9];
        m.getValues(values);
        float scaleX = values[Matrix.MSCALE_X];
        float scaleY = values[Matrix.MSCALE_Y];
        if(scaleX > MAX_ZOOM) {
            scaleX = MAX_ZOOM;
        } else if(scaleX < MIN_ZOOM) {
            scaleX = MIN_ZOOM;
        }

        if(scaleY > MAX_ZOOM) {
            scaleY = MAX_ZOOM;
        } else if(scaleY < MIN_ZOOM) {
            scaleY = MIN_ZOOM;
        }

        values[Matrix.MSCALE_X] = scaleX;
        values[Matrix.MSCALE_Y] = scaleY; 
        m.setValues(values);
    }

    public boolean getFlag(boolean b) {
        return falg = b;
    }

    /** Determine the space between the first two fingers */
    private static float spacing(MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
        float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
        return FloatMath.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
    }

    /** Calculate the mid point of the first two fingers */
    private static void midPoint(PointF point, MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);
        float y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);
        point.set(x / 2, y / 2);
    }

    private void matrixTurning(Matrix matrix, ImageView view) {

        float[] value = new float[9];
        matrix.getValues(value);
        float[] savedValue = new float[9];
        savedMatrix2.getValues(savedValue);

        // view size
        int width = view.getWidth();
        int height = view.getHeight();

        // image size
        Drawable d = view.getDrawable();
        if (d == null)
            return;
        int imageWidth = d.getIntrinsicWidth();
        int imageHeight = d.getIntrinsicHeight();
        int scaleWidth = (int) (imageWidth * value[0]);
        int scaleHeight = (int) (imageHeight * value[0]);

        if (value[2] < width - scaleWidth)
            value[2] = width - scaleWidth;
        if (value[5] < height - scaleHeight)
            value[5] = height - scaleHeight;
        if (value[2] > 0)
            value[2] = 0;
        if (value[5] > 0)
            value[5] = 0;

        if (value[0] > 10 || value[4] > 10) {
            value[0] = savedValue[0];
            value[4] = savedValue[4];
            value[2] = savedValue[2];
            value[5] = savedValue[5];
        }

        if (imageWidth > width || imageHeight > height) {

            if (scaleWidth < width && scaleHeight < height) {
                int target = WIDTH;

                if (imageWidth < imageHeight)
                    target = HEIGHT;

                if (target == WIDTH)
                    value[0] = value[4] = (float) width / imageWidth;
                if (target == HEIGHT)
                    value[0] = value[4] = (float) height / imageHeight;

                scaleWidth = (int) (imageWidth * value[0]);
                scaleHeight = (int) (imageHeight * value[4]);

                if (scaleWidth == width)
                    value[0] = value[4] = (float) width / imageWidth;
                if (scaleHeight == height)
                    value[0] = value[4] = (float) height / imageHeight;
            }

        } else {
            if (value[0] < 1)
                value[0] = 1;
            if (value[4] < 1)
                value[4] = 1;
        }

        scaleWidth = (int) (imageWidth * value[0]);
        scaleHeight = (int) (imageHeight * value[4]);

        if (scaleWidth < width) {
            value[2] = (float) width / 2 - (float) scaleWidth / 2;
        }
        if (scaleHeight < height) {
            value[5] = (float) height / 2 - (float) scaleHeight / 2;
        }

        matrix.setValues(value);
        savedMatrix2.set(matrix);

    }

    public void PaintSet() {

        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setDither(true);
        mPaint.setColor(0xFFFF0000);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(10);

        // getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(mDisplayMetrics);
        mEmboss = new EmbossMaskFilter(new float[] { 1, 1, 1 }, 0.4f, 6, 3.5f);
        mBlur = new BlurMaskFilter(24, BlurMaskFilter.Blur.NORMAL);
    }

    public void colorChanged(int color) {
        mPaint.setColor(color);
    }
}

class PaintView extends ImageView {

    private Bitmap mBitmap;
    private Canvas mCanvas;
    private Path mPath;
    private Paint mBitmapPaint;

    // onDraw
    private Paint mPaint;

    // onTouch
    private float mX, mY;
    private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;

    public PaintView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public PaintView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(1024, 1024, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        mPath = new Path();
        mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // canvas.drawColor(0xFFAAAAAA);
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        mCanvas = canvas;
        // canvas = mCanvas;
         canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);
        // canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, PaintScreen.matrix, mBitmapPaint);
        canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);

    }

    public void clear() {
        mPaint.reset();
        // invalidate();
    }

    public void setMPaint(Paint paint) {
        mPaint = paint;
    }

    private void touchStart(float x, float y) {
        // mPath.reset();
        mPath.moveTo(x, y);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
    }

    private void touchMove(float x, float y) {
        float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
        float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
        if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
            mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX) / 2, (y + mY) / 2);
            mX = x;
            mY = y;
        }
    }

    private void touchUp() {
        mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
        // commit the path to our offscreen
        mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
        // kill this so we don't double draw
        mPath.reset();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();

        Log.d("PaintView", "ev ->" + event.getAction());

        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            touchStart(x, y);
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            touchMove(x, y);
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            touchUp();
            invalidate();
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void cMatrix(Matrix matrix) {
        mCanvas.setMatrix(matrix);
    }

}
```